# Loading .aspx page

Tags: asp.net

We have a HTML page(suppose links.html) with many links. When I click on certain link it redirects me to new HTML page(for one link one new html page) and data related to that link will be displayed on that new html page from SQL server. Now coming to our requirement we need to create a new single `.aspx` page which should display the data from SQL server dynamically based on the link which we click on the `links.html` page.

My questions are:

1. Should I change the code of links.html page `onclick` event so that it can re-direct me to new `.aspx` page?
2. How can I pass the value of particular link on link.html page to new .aspx page so that it displays that selected link data?

Comment: I suggest you read up on the query parameters of a URL, and how you're receiving ASP page interprets those query parameters. **Hint:** sometimes these are called GET params, and sometimes they are called POST params.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass information using the Query String, for example:

On your HTML:

```
<a href="MyPage.aspx?linkID=9">Goto page 9</a>
```

Then in your ASPX code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    String linkID = Request.QueryString["linkID"];    
}
```

Comment: There are many links in links.html page. I think going and adding query string to each anchor tag is time taking and passing the value in the form of query string is not safe.Is there any way to pass the value of anchor tag to new .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common solutions to this problem are:

1. Query string parameters

   Pros:

   - Very simple to see what values are being passed.
   - Built-in .NET capability.
   - Useful for bookmark or favorites functionality in an application, because the page can be loaded up using the query string value; not dependent upon data being in a certain state in the application.

   Cons:

   - Each browser has a theoretical limit with Internet Explorer being the smallest at 2,048 characters.
   - Passing representation of objects is not possible with query strings (i.e. a list of `Customer` class objects).
   - Represents a potential security risk in that values are exposed. DO NOT pass any sensitive information in a query string.
2. In-process session state variables

   Pros:

   - Built-in .NET capability.
   - Allows for storage of large and complex objects, such as list of `Customer` objects.
   - Resides in memory so you do not need to remember to keep on passing the value between page navigation.

   Cons:

   - It is volatile as it is in memory, must keep checking to see if data is actually there or not.
   - Can significantly increase the memory usage of your application; this is an issue if you are not the only application on your server.